How to replace all chars of a string by theirs ASCII code in bash using sed?
I have this code but it does not work :
w(){ 
  echo $(printf "%d" "'$1")
}
echo $(w "a")
t="abcd"
echo "$t" | sed "s/./(w &)/g"
echo "$t" | sed "s/./$(w &)/g"

I get :
97
(w a)(w b)(w c)(w d) 
0000

I want
979899100

I tried putting ' or " around w or $(w &), as advised by the documentation, nothing works.
What did I miss ?
EDIT
keeping on my searches, I found this
export -f w
I tried but I'm facing new problems, and I found nothing explaning them on the web.
First code:
function w(){
echo $(printf "%d" "'$1")
}
export -f w
t="abcd"
echo $t | sed 's/./w &/eg' 

I get
97

The option 'g' doesn't work. Why ?
Second code :
function w(){
echo $(printf "%d" "'$1")
}
export -f w
t="abcd"
echo $t | sed 's/./$(w &)/eg' 

Now I get :
/bin/sh: 979899100: command not found

I don't understand why with the second code I get "command not found", and not with the first. Because I ask for evaluation with $(..) ?
P.S. May be I should create a new question ?

There's rarely any point in writing echo $(command). Just write command.

You need to loop over the characters in the string, and call w on each one. sed will not call a shell function itself.

Please edit your question and add your desired output (no description) for that sample input.

Hint: t="abcd"; for ((i=0; i<${#t}; i++)); do echo "${t:i:1}"; done

echo $t | od -An -t d1???

@oguzismail needs -v too : yes 123456789abcdef | head -10 | od -An -t d1

what is the desired output? Your code implies you want 979899100 but this is ambiguous

the only time when you use echo $(command) is when you need to trim all extra whitespaces and convert newline to space in the output of command. See https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award#echo

@oguzismail: Btw.: od behaves unexpectedly from the seventeenth letter onwards.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed 's/./ \\"\\&/g;s/.*/printf "%d"&/e' file

Convert each character into the form printf accepts.
Then prepend the printf and its first parameter and evaluate each line in turn.

This don't work if string contain double quote.

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub yes see edit

Bravo ! That's exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you.

@joel76 Of course if you want all values concatenated, without space, you just have to drop \n ; command become: printf '%d'  ${string//?/ \'&}

Byte code in bash
From version 5.2 of bash, you could convert whole string in 1 step, by using parameter expansion:
string=abcd
printf '%d\n'  ${string//?/ \'&}

97
98
99
100

Or, (strictly as requested) without newlines:
string=abcd
printf '%d'  ${string//?/ \'&}

979899100

Where (from man bash:)

//  for Pattern substitution,
? Matches any single character and
any unquoted instances  of & in string are replaced with the matching portion of pattern.

Into an array:
Convert string to array of byte codes in a very quick way:
Note: For testing, I use an UTF-8 string!
string='哦，多麼美好的一天 : Oh quelle belle journée'
printf -v _values ' %d '  ${string//?/ \'&}
read -a value <<<"${_values// 0 / 32 }"

Then
declare -p value

declare -a value=([0]="21734" [1]="65292" [2]="22810" [3]="40636" [4]="32654" [5
]="22909" [6]="30340" [7]="19968" [8]="22825" [9]="32" [10]="58" [11]="32" [12]=
"79" [13]="104" [14]="32" [15]="113" [16]="117" [17]="101" [18]="108" [19]="108"
 [20]="101" [21]="32" [22]="98" [23]="101" [24]="108" [25]="108" [26]="101" [27]
="32" [28]="106" [29]="111" [30]="117" [31]="114" [32]="110" [33]="233" [34]="10
1")

You could iterate over your array simply:
for val in ${value[@]}; do
    printf -v char %X $val
    printf 'Value: %5d char: %b\n' $val "\U$char"
done

Value: 21734 char: 哦
Value: 65292 char: ，
Value: 22810 char: 多
  ︙      ︙    ︙  ︙
Value:   110 char: n
Value:   233 char: é
Value:   101 char: e

Same using hexadecimal:
string='哦，多麼美好的一天 : Oh quelle belle journée'
printf -v _values ' %X '  ${string//?/ \'&}
read -a value <<<"${_values// 0 / 20 }"
declare -p value

declare -a value=([0]="54E6" [1]="FF0C" [2]="591A" [3]="9EBC" [4]="7F8E" [5]="59
7D" [6]="7684" [7]="4E00" [8]="5929" [9]="20" [10]="3A" [11]="20" [12]="4F" [13]
="68" [14]="20" [15]="71" [16]="75" [17]="65" [18]="6C" [19]="6C" [20]="65" [21]
="20" [22]="62" [23]="65" [24]="6C" [25]="6C" [26]="65" [27]="20" [28]="6A" [29]
="6F" [30]="75" [31]="72" [32]="6E" [33]="E9" [34]="65")

Reverse conversion
printf -v newString '%b' ${value[@]/#/\\U}
declare -p newString

declare -- newString="哦，多麼美好的一天 : Oh quelle belle journée"

Using byte values instead of characters:
For converting a string into byte values, one simple way is to create a funtion and localize locales as non UTF:
toBytes() {
    local LC_ALL=C LANG=C values
    printf -v values \ %d\  ${2//?/ \'&}
    read -a $1 <<<${values// 0 / 32 }
}

Usage: toBytes <array variable name> "<string to convert>":
toBytes array '哦，多麼美好的一天 : Oh quelle belle journée'
declare -p array

declare -a array=([0]="229" [1]="147" [2]="166" [3]="239" [4]="188" [5]="140" [6
]="229" [7]="164" [8]="154" [9]="233" [10]="186" [11]="188" [12]="231" [13]="190
" [14]="142" [15]="229" [16]="165" [17]="189" [18]="231" [19]="154" [20]="132" [
21]="228" [22]="184" [23]="128" [24]="229" [25]="164" [26]="169" [27]="32" [28]=
"58" [29]="32" [30]="79" [31]="104" [32]="32" [33]="113" [34]="117" [35]="101" [
36]="108" [37]="108" [38]="101" [39]="32" [40]="98" [41]="101" [42]="108" [43]="
108" [44]="101" [45]="32" [46]="106" [47]="111" [48]="117" [49]="114" [50]="110"
 [51]="195" [52]="169" [53]="101")

Converting byte array into string
printf -v newstring \\%o ${array[@]}
printf %b\\n $newstring

哦，多麼美好的一天 : Oh quelle belle journée

With some options:
toBytes() { 
    local LC_ALL=C LANG=C values repl=32 fmt=d
    case $1 in 
        -o) shift; repl=40 fmt=o ;;
        -x) shift; repl=20 fmt=x ;;
    esac
    printf -v values \ %$fmt\  ${2//?/ \'&}
    read -a $1 <<< ${values// 0 / $repl }
}

Usage: toBytes [-o|-x] <array variable name> "<string to convert>"
toBytes -x array "That's all folks!"
printf '%b' ${array[@]/#/\\x}
That's all folks!


Came here to write the same so I won't repeat the answer. But it might be more useful to readers if you add an explanation of what is going on inside the printf oneliner.

@TasosPapastylianou Answer edited!

Of course if you want all values concatenated, without space, you just have to drop \n ; command become: printf '%d'  ${string//?/ \'&}

Easier in Perl:
echo abcd | perl -lne 'print ord for split //'


-n reads the input line by line and runs the code for each line;
-l removes a newline from the input and adds it to output;
split using an empty pattern splits a string into individual characters;
ord returns the codepoint of a character.


Thank you ! I already did it in Perl, but your solution is much better than mine.

sed cannot convert chars to their ASCII codes (at least, not without some insane, non-portable combination of hieroglyphics). You can add a sed command to pre-format input or post-format the output of some other tool that can do that (e.g. bash printf, od, awk, perl, etc.), but then what's the point when you can just use 1 tool to do it instead of 2, the tool that does the conversion plus sed?
Using GNU awk for it's ordchr library and splitting into chars given a null FS:
$ t="abcd"
$ echo "$t" | awk -l ordchr 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i=ord($i)} 1'
979899100

or using any awk:
$ echo "$t" | awk '
    BEGIN {
        for ( i=0; i<256; i++ ) {
            ords[ sprintf("%c", i) ] = i 
        }
    }
    {
        n = length($0)
        for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) {
            printf "%s", ords[ substr($0, i, 1) ]
        }
        print ""
    }
'
979899100


Great. I was looking for a solution with "awk" after the solution using "sed" given by @potong. I have learnt a lot of bash/sed/awk today. Thank you everybody !

Here's a simple while loop over characters using Bash substring indexing:
w() { while [ "$1" ]; do printf '(w %d)' "'${1::1}"; set -- "${1:1}"; done; }

w abcd  # (w 97)(w 98)(w 99)(w 100)

Not sure though if this is the output format you expected.
